# What is the main difference between using Eclipse with Android plugin AND using Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

What are the main differences between using Eclipse with the Android plugin and the standard Android Studio?

Which one do you recommend? (I guess it varies with how we plan to use it).

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: The difference is simple: Eclipse is terrible and Android Studio is a million times better. There is no reason to use Eclipse, especially since Android Studio is the official IDE for Android development.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Android Studio, Eclipse is no longer supported. You can import your Eclipse projects and use them in android studio. Also check the following questions:

[Android Studio vs Eclipse with ADT (2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574732/android-studio-vs-eclipse-with-adt-2015)

[Which Android IDE is better - Android Studio or Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849078/which-android-ide-is-better-android-studio-or-eclipse)

Finally, I found the following two reasons to be great positives to use Android Studio:

It supports gradle (this allows you to really have control over the build, create different application flavors, different signing configurations and so on).

It feels better. From doing a refactoring (like renaming a method, to extracting a class) to viewing the Logcat. The refactoring seem more solid and the Logcat does not "disappear" as it happens in Eclipse.

Comment: *It feels better.* I think we can agree that is highly subjective

Comment: Well, all other points are not so I'll stick with Android Studio :) Thanks for the links

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is basically for Java program development and used for Android with ADT, whereas Android Studio is available specifically for Android development and you will get a lot of help with it.
Studio is definitely better for designing layouts running emulators.
Studio provides better debugging and help popups when you start coding.

I would recommend you go ahead with Android Studio as it will prove to be helpful even if you stuck somewhere with the method names or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse sucks. Go for Android Studio which is based on the unbeatable Java IDE - IntelliJ Idea (known as JetBrains Idea these days).

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio uses the dependency and gradle structure whereas eclipse do not use it.

I recommend you to use Android Studio. It is the Best for Android Programming. Some newer updates are not available in Eclipse. Android Studio does has.

Answer (score 0):

These are few positives :

1. No R file errors, it gets generated at compile time and uses stub for development.
2. Very good and fast autocomplete feature
3. Preview of resources (Drawables, styles, etc) along side code
4. List of layouts used in a class file
5. Analyse code and fixes it using single click (LINT tool is used for this). This tool is very good, you also learn about your mistakes too
6. References of methods (shows parts of code from where a method is called)
7. Builtin support for ANT, Maven, gradle, git, svn, etc, etc
8. No need for extra plugins for Android
9. Better visual editor than Eclipse

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer!