# New android application project

Tags: android

I am creating a new application using eclipse, I wrote the application name and other things, then selected the target SDK, but in "compile with" I can't select anything because "choices" is null, what is the problem?

Comment: Switch to Android Studio!!

Comment: If for some reason you need to stick to Eclipse, provide screenshots of your problem.

Comment: @PrerakSola There is no reason you CANNOT use eclipse, he just has issues with it. Doesn't mean you should be discouraged from using eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to learn android. Start with Android studio. [Eclipse is not supported now](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html).

However if you do insist see this page, it might take you few installation to get it right on the first time you can always delete eclipse but restart the system to really clean it. And you should install a matching SDK according to this page:

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

Add a screenshot of your screen , but as Prerak Sola suggested Android Studio is the front runner IDE when it comes to Android  development and Eclipse is in history.

Why you should switch??

[Take a look at this link](http://insights.dice.com/2014/03/19/googles-android-studio-vs-eclipse-fits-needs/)

[This as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574732/android-studio-vs-eclipse-with-adt-2015)

Comment: I can't load image because my reputation is less than 10  :(

Comment: You need to install the android plugin

Comment: Am add a screenshot :)

Comment: There is no reason you CANNOT use eclipse, he just has issues with it. Doesn't mean you should be discouraged from using eclipse.

Comment: @sivi  what is the plugin I need ?

Comment: I thought it is the android one. Yu seem to have it. I would try reinstall eclipse if you really need to use it