# How can i see the preview in eclipse adt while coding in xml?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt

I cannot see an window showing preview for xml in the eclipse adt.
please help.

Comment: **while coding in xml** means do you want it like Android Studio ??

Comment: Did you checked my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38278566/3981656

Comment: @janki gadhiya yes like android studio.

Comment: see my answer below @MattCutts

Answer (score 0):

Click `Graphical Layout` Tab . near the `YOUR_FILE_NAME.xml` Tab

[image: Answer]

Comment: like while type the code in xml a preview seen in the android studio

Comment: that type of facility not in Eclipse

Comment: you using android studio or eclipse. which is better?

Comment: Android Studio is better .

Comment: Accept my answer if this answer help u

Comment: but when i using it takes a lot time to gradle and the disk usage is high. what about you?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849078/which-android-ide-is-better-android-studio-or-eclipse and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574732/android-studio-vs-eclipse-with-adt-2015 to which one is better

Answer (score 0):

Select **Graphical Layout** Tab in xml editor.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i see the preview in eclipse adt **while coding in xml**?

**It is not Possible.** The functionality is not included in Eclipse. It is there in Android Studio i.e. you can see layout changes with corresponding code change side by side the functionality comes with the name tab `preview`.

**I recommend you switch to Android Studio for that.**

This may be useful to you : [Where is Android Studio layout preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview)